# Comparing 2 files in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare two files and add some information after it.

My file 1 looks like:

```
1   234 332     4   
2   345 435     6
3   546 325     3
4   984 493     9
```

My file2 looks like

```
1   234 332     a   b   c   d   
2   345 435     a   b   c   d
4   984 493     a   b   c   d
```

And I want the following output

```
1   234 332     4   a   b   c   d
2   345 435     6   a   b   c   d  
4   984 493     9   a   b   c   d
```

In other words:
I want to compare columns 1,2 and 3. If they are equal I want column 4 of file 1 and after that the rest of columns in file 2.

I have written the following code in Python:

```
with open('file1.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt') as f2, open('output_file.txt', 'w') as outfile:

for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):

columns1 = line1.rstrip("\n").split("\t")

columns2 = line2.rstrip("\n").split("\t")

    if columns1[0] == columns2[0] and columns1[1] == columns2[1] and columns1[2] == columns2[2]:

    print >> outfile, columns2[0],columns2[1],columns2[2],columns1[3],columns2[3],columns2[4],columns2[5],columns2[6]
```

And I obtain the following result:

```
1   234 332     4   a   b   c   d  
2   345 435     6   a   b   c   d
```

My problem is that my code is comparing line by line

```
line1 with line1

line2 with line2
```

When my code compares line3 with line3 they are not equal and the program stop.
How can I do to compare line3 with line4 and so on... if lines 3 didn't match???

Comment: Your problem isn't the fact that your code is comparing line by line, but that you aren't comparing each line to each line in your loop.  You will need nested loops in order to cross-check each entry.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't expect your files to be too large, why not just iterate through each line for each line, then break when/if you find a match (the break assumes you expect no more than one match per line).

```
f1 = open('file1.txt')
f2 =  open('file2.txt') 
outfile =  open('output_file.txt', 'w') 

for line1 in f1:
    columns1 = line1.rstrip("\n").split("\t")
    for line2 in f2:
        columns2 = line2.rstrip("\n").split("\t")

        if columns1[0] == columns2[0] and columns1[1] == columns2[1] and columns1[2] == columns2[2]:

            print >> outfile, columns2[0],columns2[1],columns2[2],columns1[3],columns2[3],columns2[4],columns2[5],columns2[6]
            break
f1.close()
f2.close()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Your answer seems correct to me but still didn't work (same problem, the script stops in the last line that match, forgetting the following lines)